# Validate ModelForm without checking duplicate

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a view in django which checks if a client exists then it does nothing. If it doesn't exist then I create.

This is what the ModelForm looks like:

```
class FacebookLoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['facebook_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

And here is my code:

```
def facebook_login(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    form = FacebookLoginForm(data)

    if form.is_valid():
       # do something
       pass
```

However for some reason when I call `is_valid` on the form it checks that the passed data doesn't exist in the database (where the model fields are unique). How can I set the ModelForm to just validate the data without checking if it already exists? My ultimate goal is to validate the input of the form and then update/create the database.

Comment: Have you considered using a regular `Form` and not a `ModelForm`? Or are you constrained to using a `ModelForm`?

Comment: @Danielholmes No I'm not constrained, I just thought it would be cleaner code

Comment: The `is_valid` method is not validating the data you sent against the database content at all. It just validate the data received is well formatted based on the model definition. Which means, that if the first_name cannot be null in the model, the form will not be valid if it's not present.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying the email already exists without me saving a new entry

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stick with a `ModelForm` you can override the `validate_unique` method, which looks like this:

```
def validate_unique(self):
    """
    Calls the instance's validate_unique() method and updates the form's
    validation errors if any were raised.
    """
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
    try:
        self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)
```

However, you are prbably better off just creating a regular form because it will serve your purpose just fine. Overriding the `validate_unique` function in this case would not be cleaner code IMO.

**EDIT**:
A better solution would be to override the clean method without calling the `super`. From the source code in `BaseModelForm` `__init__` method:

> ```
>     # self._validate_unique will be set to True by BaseModelForm.clean().
>     # It is False by default so overriding self.clean() and failing to call
>     # super will stop validate_unique from being called.
> ```

So this is actually how your form should look:

```
class FacebookLoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['facebook_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: This is a basic case for a sign-in form that uses the `User` model as the model for the Form. Creating a normal Form to do this with an existing model seems to validate DRY IMHO.